# Can't configure Cloudflare CNAME to point to Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, cloudflare, cname

I've setup my amazon bucket so that it's named media.example.com

Then, I've set a CNAME "media.example.com" pointing to "media.example.com.s3.amazonaws.com"
However, If I try to go to media.example.com, I get a Page not found error.

![enter image description here][1]

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'd thank any advice :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried Nginx S3 proxy? https://coderwall.com/p/rlguog/nginx-as-proxy-for-amazon-s3-public-private-files

Answer (score -2):

This issue here seems like you have got the Amazon S3 url wrong, try and set the CNAME `media.example.com` point to `s3.amazonaws.com/media.example.com/<foldername>`

`<foldername>` to be replaced with the name of the folder that you have created inside the bucket (if any).